# How to set file attachment in android

Tags: android

I am creating a file and then sending it as  attachment mail in background from my app.All is working fine mail sending is done successfully but issue is here that while creating file i named it as abc.csv and it file stored in dir with this name but when i got the attachment then it is named as **<<_mnt_sdcard_MyTest_abc.csv>>**. Here is the code which i am using to get the attachment.

```
 private boolean SendMail() {
  boolean result=false;
  txtAdd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
  File folder;
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
              + getString(R.string.app_name));
     boolean var = false;
        if (!folder.exists())
            var = folder.mkdir();
  Mail m = new Mail("abc@gmail.com", "*****"); 
  //String[] toArr = {EmailFetcher.getEmail(this)}; 
  String[] toArr = {txtAdd.getText().toString()};
  m.setTo(toArr); 
  m.setFrom("abc@gmail.com"); 
  m.setSubject("XXXXXXXXX"); 
  m.setBody("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); 
  try { 
    m.addAttachment(folder+"/abc.csv"); 
      if(m.send()) {
          result= true;
    } else { 
        result= false;
    } 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
   Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
  } 
  return result;
```

}

How to set the file name in attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this it`s work for me.

```
public void sendImageInEmail(String filePath) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String html = "<html><body><center>Created By ZalaJanakSinh<center></body></html>";

            String address = "";

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address });
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Created By Zala JanakSinh");

            //need this to prompts email client only

            email.setType("text/html");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml(html));

            email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            email.setType("image/*");                   

            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
            myContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in SendImageInEmail==>"+e.toString());
        }
```

best of Luck Dear

Comment: i donot want to use any chooser here i am sending mail from background

Comment: @Supreet just implement and after see the result ok

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh Would I be able to implement this also to send a file with giving the options to user (ex. email, bluetooth)?